# Custom entry in the contextual menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, contextmenu

Dropbox adds a custom entry in the Mac OS contextual menu, so that if I am in the Dropbox folder and right click on a file or folder, I see a Dropbox entry.

How is it possible to add an entry in the system-wide contextual menu? Are there any hacks? How can I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it just within an App, check out this article from Apple named [Displaying a Contextual Menu](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/DisplayContextMenu.html)

But I'm guessing you want to do this for all contextual menus, the bottom of the page I referred you to above talks about how to create a "Contextual Menu Plug-in" (or CFPlugin) installed in a `"Library/Contextual Menu Items"` directory.  Here's the [reference guide for plug-ins](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPlugIns/CFPlugIns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000128i) and [CFPlugins](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPlugIns/CFPlugIns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000128i).  It also mentions you need to implement some Carbon Menu Manager functionality, but I'm not certain if that's appropriate in 10.6 or 10.7.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your answer. You finally brought me on the right way. Yes I want to add the entry in the system-wide contextual menu. The answer is that I have to inject my code in Finder. So at the moment I am studying the mach_star project. (https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star).

Comment: `CFPlugin` is a generic class for creating plugins for any application, FYI. You can add to the context menu by creating a 'Service', but that's not how dropbox does it. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html

Comment: How do you think DropBox does it then ?