# Contextual Menu Plugins for Leopard OS

Tags: objective-c, plugins, macos-carbon, appleevents

I am writing Contextual Menu Plugins for Leopard OS and referring [Writing Contextual Menu Plugins for OS X, part 1](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.18/18.08/MenuPlugins/index.html) article by Brent Simmons. My plugin is working fine.

[image]
Is there any way to move my test menu into main menu (above the Label)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

The OS controls what gets displayed in that menu, so in order to change it around, you would need to call private methods, reimplement system-level functionality, and just in general do some Very Bad Things which would be unsafe, could break at a moment's notice, and possibly work differently between even dot releases of the same OS.

Comment: Do you know how to re-implement system level functionality and private method names?

Comment: There's some info about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294335/how-to-write-os-x-finder-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called a system service, and was introduced in OS X 10.5. I know for a fact that many applications can do this, and Automator routines can be triggered this way because Automator itself is a system service. To see a service applicable for an application (i.e. Finder) go to the Application menu on the top bar (for lack of better name T_T), such as the Finder bolded text, and go down to Services > and it will show you all services that can be used in the app. If you need pointers on how to build this, just comment here.

EDIT: Yes, a SIMBL plugin is also considered a service, and on second read of your question, that's what you want.

Comment: system service is also coming in more option.

Comment: If that's what you'd like, then it may be worth noting that it will only show through the Services > in the context menu. SIMBL has further integrated support. This is all in light of the Finder Cocoa rewrite in 10.6.

Comment: Dropbox contextual menu is coming in main menu on Leopard.

Comment: They do a quick and dirty Finder hack to get it to work, mach_star: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156251/custom-entry-in-the-contextual-menu